# Problema com leitura da serial

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, serial

Galera, estou tentando ler dados de uma porta serial em c#, porém junto com os dados esta sendo retornado muito "lixo", o que torna impossível a conversão da string para inteiro. Tem alguma maneira de fazer que eu não perca tantos dados?

```
    private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) //evento datareceived da portaserial atualizado por um timer com intervalo de 3ms
    {
        if (SerialCOM.IsOpen)
        {
            SerialPort sData = (SerialPort)sender;
            { 
                sData.DiscardInBuffer();
                int data;
                if (sData.BytesToRead > 0) RxString += sData.ReadExisting();
                var teste = RxString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                data = Convert.ToInt32(teste[contador]);
            }
     }
```

Com esse código eu tenho no array "teste[]" vários valores inteiros em formato de string, mas quando tento converter esses números para inteiro mostra a seguinte mensagem: "A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.". Tentei usar TryParse para conversão porém perco muitos dados, o que não pode acontecer na minha aplicação. Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

EDIT:

```
//supondo que RxString seja
RxString = "1234 456 789 1341 1334";
//então teste[] será
teste[0] = 1234
teste[1] = 456
teste[2] = 789
teste[3] = 1341
teste[4] = 1334
```

O correto seria esse, o que seria fácil converter, porém as vezes chega informação vazia ou lixo na string "RxString", o que causa erro na hora da conversão.

Comment: Consegue colocar na sua questão um exemplo da informação que recebe da porta? Basicamente o conteúdo do `teste[]`.

Comment: sim, só um momento, vou atualizar amigo.

Comment: Diz que usando o `TryParse` perde muitos dados, como assim?

Comment: Como o TryParse retorna false quando a conversão não é possível e true quando é completada, eu só posso usar os dados que foram convertidos. Os que não são convertidos devido ao formato incorreto eu perco.

Comment: Na minha aplicação se eu perder dados vou estar comprometendo outra parte do programa.

Comment: Certo, mas se o `TryParse` não consegue converter algo em número, então é porque a `string` que veio não é um número válido, certo?

Comment: isso mesmo amigo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88350/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-felipe-mateus).

Comment: Diminua o baud rate e verifique se melhora.

Comment: Por curiosidade: sua placa de Arduino tem o desenho do mapa da Itália, nas costas da placa?